# Dockerfile OpenApi Generator

Tags: docker, swagger, openapi-generator

I am trying to avoid importing all kinds of dependencies in my docker images (by way of npm or java) so that I can generate a swagger client.

I am using [openapitools/openapi-generator-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/) but when I try and use it, the command `generate` isn't found. Here are the [docs](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#16---docker)

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
FROM openapitools/openapi-generator-cli
RUN generate
```

Result:

```
Step 1/2 : FROM openapitools/openapi-generator-cli
 ---> 62d78bf45d59
Step 2/2 : RUN generate
 ---> Running in accaf10464d5
/bin/sh: 1: generate: not found
```

However, this works without issue:

```
docker run openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate
```

And by "works" I mean I get positive feedback from the cli that I'm missing the required args.

Being relatively new to this part of Docker, is my understanding incorrect with how `FROM` should be working here? I think I'm hitting the error because `FROM` doesn't actually run the container and therefore `generator` isn't present.

But what confuses me is I do the exact same process with `dotnet` and it works perfectly fine.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bullseye-slim
RUN dotnet
```

Results:

```
Step 1/2 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bullseye-slim
 ---> 32aef79fd915
Step 2/2 : RUN dotnet
 ---> Running in 1e6c04d30a82

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker run openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate`

works because it's equivalent `bash /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh generate` inside the container

Because from the Dockerfile `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`  is set as an `ENTRYPOINT`, for you case check [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) from the github repo and grasp the logic on what happens when you pass generate, or simply do

```
FROM openapitools/openapi-generator-cli
RUN bash /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh generate
```